# pulling ifindex via get-netadapter then passing to new-netIpaddress

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to set ip addresses on specific VM network cards via invoke-vmscript

when i run

Invoke-VMScript -VM vmname -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText '($adapter = get-netadapter -InterfaceDescription Vm* | Select-Object ifindex).adapter'

i get the desired Ifindex of 4 stored in the variable $adapter(i am filtering based on VMnetx adapters

but when i try to pass that to

Invoke-VMScript -VM name -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText '(Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $adapter -ServerAddresses ("x.x.x.x","x.x.x.x"))'

i get

Set-DnsClientServerAddress : Cannot validate
argument on parameter 'InterfaceIndex'. The argument is null. Provide a
|  valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.

so it seems that the variable is not providing a valid number.

I was expecting it to pass the variable to the script text

Comment: You are missing the `@` to make it an array : `@("x.x.x.x","x.x.x.x")`

Comment: Do you mean `$adapter = Invoke-VMScript -VM vmname -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText '(Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription Vm*).ifindex'`? As your code is now, `$adapter` is only valid **inside** the scriptblock. You need to capture that output on the `Invoke-VMScript`

Comment: yes, thank you, now it shows as expected, Thanks Theo your a gent